# How to perform partition on a drive where ubuntu is installed?

Tags: partitioning

I have only one drive with 461.81GB and want to shrink the volume by 300 GB, and create another two volumes using that space...
How do I do that using Gparted??

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a Live USB stick, run it and shrink your drive from gparted inside the Live so you wont have the lock on your HDD